# Can CoreBluetooth act as both a central and peripheral at the same time (Unknown error 0)?

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have an OSX app that does the following:

1. Start the central manager `[[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:queue:]` and wait for it to initialize.
2. Connect to a Bluetooth LE peripheral using `[CBCentralManager connectPeripheral:options:]`
3. Start the peripheral manager `[[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:queue:options:]` and wait for it to initialize.
4. Add services to the peripheral manager `[CBPeripheralManager addService:]` and wait for them to finish being added.
5. Start advertising [`[CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheralManager/startAdvertising%3a) and wait for the result.

Now, my callback `[CBPeripheralManagerDelegate peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising:error:]` gets an error: “Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error." UserInfo=0x7fb23bf7ba50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error.}”.

However, if I call `[CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:]` immediately before `startAdvertising:`, then the error goes away.

Is it impossible for a Mac to act in both Central Role and Peripheral Role at the same time?  Does this limitation also exist on iOS? Is this a hardware-specific limitation, or is this inherent in Bluetooth LE?

I am testing this on a Mid 2011 Mac Mini running OSX 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: I have a similar situation: I have 2 processes running on the mac: A peripheral and a central. Central does not see the peripheral even though a scanner running on iOS does. The central does see and interact with other (non locally-running) peripherals. No clue why, still investigating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm CoreBluetooth on iOS doesn't have this issue, at least not when I last tested it on iOS 6 on an iPhone 5. The iPhone can advertise as a BLE peripheral while talking to another BLE peripheral as the BLE Central at the same time. I don't have results on OS X. But I will be really suprised if OS X, on a much more powerful platform, has such limit.